# How to add text at the end of a line in UNIX

Tags: unix, append

Here's how the set up is...

```
LINE W/ TEXT1
LINE W/ TEXT2
LINE W/ TEXT3
FIX W/ TEXT5
LINE W/ TEXT6
LINE W/ TEXT7
```

The idea is to get the FIX line and add '***'(3 asterisks) at the end of that line.

I've been having issues where it replaces the first word with text instead of adding to the end, been messing with this format somewhat

sed '/FIX/s/$/***/' myfile

any help?

Comment: You example `sed '/FIX/s/$/*/' myfile` works fine for me (running OS X).  If FIX was part of the regular expression of the "s" function, then it would be replaced, e.g. `sed s/FIX/*/`.

Answer (score 2):

I believe the problem is that your input file is in DOS format, so there is a carriage return before the end of each line, so your sed inserts *** after the carriage return but before the newline. You should be able to see what is going on with:

```
sed '/FIX/s/$/***/' myfile | cat -v
```

See if this works as a solution:

```
sed '/FIX/s/\([^[:cntrl:]]*\)/\1***/' myfile
```

Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

First, cleanup your file

```
dos2unix yourFile
```

Then

```
sed '/FIX/s/$/\*\*\*/' yourFile
```

**OUTPUT**

```
LINE W/ TEXT1
LINE W/ TEXT2
LINE W/ TEXT3
FIX W/ TEXT5***
LINE W/ TEXT6
LINE W/ TEXT7
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: It didn't D: it ended up doing the same issue i've been having. It went  '*** W/ TEXT 5'

Comment: Did you use dbl-quotes `"..."` or single-quotes `'...'`? You have to use single quotes for this to work. Also please edit your post to include the exact output you're getting. Good luck.

Comment: Hmm, On my system it worked either way, single or dbl quote. What OS are you using? Good luck.